# OpenVPN and MerlinWRT

Tags: openvpn, router

My ASUS router is flashed with MerlinWRT. This configuration used to work, however now when I connect I get,

```
$ sudo openvpn ./client1.ovpn
OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Apr 13 2015
UDPv4 link local: [undef]
UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]75.108.194.127:1194
TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error: error:14082174:SSL routines:SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small
TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

How do I resolve, *"SSL3_CHECK_CERT_AND_ALGORITHM:dh key too small"* using MerlinWRT.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

[The thread detailing this error can be found here](http://www.snbforums.com/threads/asuswrt-merlin-378-54_2-is-now-available.24902/page-12#post-188181). You can see RMerlin (the author) himself addressing this.

RMerlin gives a solution to fix this problem

> In the meantime as I said, simply generate a new DH, and paste it on the DH field of your router to replace it. The OpenSSL version you use does not matter, you don't need the newer version to do this.

And the code to generate the key..

```
openssl dhparam -out dh.pem 1024
cat dh.pem
```

Per RMerlin, this will be fixed..

> When 378.55 is released, which won't be for at least a few weeks, as the current Asus GPL code has numerous issues.

For some background, this bug is not in MerlinWRT's code but a patch to the [client OpenSSL library](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2639-1/),

> As a security improvement, this update also modifies OpenSSL behaviour to reject DH key sizes below 768 bits, preventing a possible downgrade
>   attack.

Though interestingly, according to the ["Guide to Deploying Diffie-Hellman for TLS"](https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html) you may want to consider 2048-bit or stronger.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor tidbit.  I know this is a Linux site, but I also ran into this exact issue during my use of `Windows`, even though the key I generated was `2048bit`.  Not sure if it is the same, but `openvpn-install-2.3.7-I601-x86_64` doesn't yield the error, while `openvpn-install-2.3.7-I602-x86_64` does.  The older version worked.  I uninstalled the new one, installed the old one and was up and running again.  Perhaps there is a reversion that is causing it?

The error message was exactly the same as what OP stated.  May I suggest trying an older version of the client on your individual system?

The server is an `Asus RT-AC87u` running `Asuswrt-Merlin` with firmware `378.51`.

Comment: Clearly not the same problem. You dropped that key into the web interface and Windows was still giving you a problem you need to find a solution and report a bug.